# Rollback a Rocketeer Update

Tags: php, deployment

I've started using Rocketeer to deploy PHP projects.  It has the ability to rollback if you publish a release that causes a problem.  However, it doesn't look like you can rollback an update (an update just pulls changes from a repo, whereas a release does a new clone of the repo).  Anyone know if it's possible to rollback an update in Rocketeer?

http://rocketeer.autopergamene.eu/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creator of Rocketeer here, answer is you can't. Reason is even if I could store which commit was deployed before the `git pull`, Rocketeer has no knowledge of whichever task or operation you may run in addition of that, and so I can't rollback anything around it. So even if it would work technically, it would most likely cause a lot of unexpected user errors.

That being said, you can redeploy a specific commit (the one you had before the update) via `rocketeer deploy --branch="commit"`